# Trayendo campos especificos de un modelo en otro, a través de relaciones entre los dos

Tags: python, django, django-models, base-de-datos

Estoy trabajando con la aplicación `django-smart-selects` para desplegar campos específicos de formularios acorde a las opciones dadas en los mismos, y tengo los siguientes modelos:

`Session` tiene una relacion `ManyToMany` con `Metrics`.

Archivo `models.py`:

```
class Session(models.Model):

    corporal_structures = models.ForeignKey(SingleBodySegment)
    movement = ChainedManyToManyField(
        Movements,
        chained_field = 'corporal_structures',
        chained_model_field = 'corporal_segments'
    )

    metrics = models.ManyToManyField(Metrics, blank=True)

    date_session_begin = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now())
    date_session_end = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now())
    observations = models.TextField(blank=False)


class Metrics(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
     equation = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
     min_value = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5,decimal_places=3)
     max_value = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5,decimal_places=3)

     def __str__(self):
        return "%s" % self.name
```

Gracias a la relación `ManyToMany`, en el formulario de `Sessions` (via django admin) me aparece el listado de las métricas del modelo `Metrics`, pero solo el atributo `name` de una instancia de `Metrics` me aparece en el `select multiple` en el formulario.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Además del nombre, deseo poder traerme para seleccionar los atributos equation, min_value, max_value.

En la tabla `Metrics` es donde creo una instancia de `Metrics`, pero cuando se crea una sesión en `Session` debo indicar un valor de `Metrics` para esa sesión con sus respectivos campos nativos que son estos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo hago para traerme los otros campos y tenerlos disponibles?

Si ya he asociado a `Metrics` y `Session` con una relación `ManyToMany` debería aprovechar ello para hacer lo que quiero ¿verdad?

Comment: Que versión estás usando? La última versión ya no me funciona.

En dado caso, revisaste la documentación, para ManytoMany tienes que usar los auxiliares de la librería específicos para ManytoMany.

Comment: ¿Los auxiliares de la libreria?

Comment: Mira acá, esto te puede servir: https://github.com/digi604/django-smart-selects#chained-manytomany-selects

Si funciona me avisas para ponerlo como respuesta y ganarme unos punticos :D

Comment: @SalahAdDin Si, claro, la forma de "encadenar" o jerarquizar elementos en campos de multiples selecciones y con relaciones `ManyToMany` es como lo he estado trabajando. Solo que no se como traerme los demás atributos del modelo `Metrics` que esta como llave foránea en `Session`, en realidad creo que esto es mas de trabajar con relationships y ORM en Django más que con el plugin de  `django-smart-selects` ...

Comment: Acorde a esta respuesta obtenida, [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35249705/getting-specific-fields-of-a-model-in-another-via-relationships-between-them]  yo solo debo en el modelo `Metrics` retornar los campos que quiero que sean mostrados en los formularios de django admin independientemente de que sean claves foráneas o no. En el modelo `Metrics`, el metodo `__str__` quedaría asi `def __str__(self):
        return "{},{},{}".format(self.name, self.equation, self.min_value, self.max_value, ) `

Comment: Y de esta manera, en donde sea llamada una instancia de `Metrics` en los formularios de administración de Django, la obtendré con todos estos atributos que estoy llamando.

Comment: Sin usar smartselects?

Comment: @SalahAdDin asi es, simplemente es a través de python, accediendo a los objetos o atributos de la clase. Ni siquiera era ORM o relationships como pensaba.

Answer (score 1):

Si lo que quieres es cambiar el string que se muestra en el select multiple, puedes simplemente modificar la representación del objeto:

```
class Metrics(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    equation = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    min_value = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5,decimal_places=3)
    max_value = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5,decimal_places=3)

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s (%s) - [%s - %s]" % (
            self.name, self.equation, 
            self.min_value, self.max_value
        )
```